# Show that the sequence $f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}$ converges pointwise to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that the sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}$ converges pointwise to $0$, ¿Is this convergence uniformly for $x\in[10,\infty)$?

*This is correct??*

My attemp: Note that, $$f'_{n}=\dfrac{n-n^3x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$$ So, if $f'_{n}=0$ then $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Furthermore, $$f''_{n}(x)=\dfrac{-6n^3x+4n^5x^3}{(1+(nx)^2)^2}\neq0$$

Therefore, if I evaluated in $x=1/n$, we have $f_n(1/n)=1/2$. Therefore, $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}{|\dfrac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}-0|}=\frac{1}{2}$$

So, $f_{n}(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$, but **not uniformly** for $x\in[10,\infty)$, because, the sup is constant, and equal to $1/2$.

*This is correct??*

Comment: But the sup is achieved at $x=1/n$, which does not lie in the interval $[10,\infty)$.

Comment: Also the root of derivative $\frac{1}{n^2}$ not $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @daulomb Since, $n-n^3x^2=0\implies x^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\implies x=\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you set $x=\frac{1}{n}$ but that is not in $[10,\infty)$. That is a good strategy to prove that something does not converge uniformly. However you must be sure that the sequence $x_n$ is also in your domain. To prove uniform convergence:
\begin{align}
\bigg\Vert \frac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}\bigg\Vert_\infty \leq \bigg\Vert \frac{nx}{(nx)^2}\bigg\Vert_\infty \leq \bigg\Vert \frac{1}{nx}\bigg\Vert_\infty \leq \frac{1}{10n}\to 0 \ \ \ \text{ as } \ n\to \infty
\end{align}
Hence the convergence is uniform as well.